# Mapnik XML mapfile projection of multiply layers

Tags: geotiff-tiff, mapnik

How to apply a multiply layer with Mapnik from EPSG:4326 TIFFs to EPSG:3875 projected tiles?

I have two TIFF files, one containing the color-relief and the other the slope-shade (generated with GDAL, which is perfectly [demonstrated here](https://blog.mastermaps.com/2012/06/creating-hillshades-with-gdaldem.html)). The slope-shade is going to be blended with the color relief image, using the [multiply blend mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Multiply). Both TIFFs are in EPSG:4326.

With Mapnik, to include the input projection (EPSG:4326) and the output projection (EPSG:3875) You have to add the `srs` to the Map and both Layer elements. This is done in the example file below. Here is an explanation by [Frederik Ramm](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/13250/what-is-the-correct-projection-i-should-use-with-mapnik/13254) about the approach.

The color-relief map is projected correctly, but *the slope-shade is not multiplied*. How can this be explained and how should the projection be modified to actually multiply the slope-shade layer with the color-relief layer?

```xml
<Map srs="+init=epsg:3857">

  <Style name="color relief style" >
    <Rule>
      <RasterSymbolizer mode="normal" />
    </Rule>
  </Style>  
  <Style name="slopeshade style">
    <Rule>
      <RasterSymbolizer opacity="0.4" mode="multiply" />
    </Rule>
  </Style>

  <Layer name="color relief" srs="+init=epsg:4326">
    <StyleName>color relief style</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
      <Parameter name="type">gdal</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="file">/path_to_dir/map_color.tif</Parameter>
    </Datasource>
  </Layer>
  <Layer name="slopeshade" srs="+init=epsg:4326">
    <StyleName>slopeshade style</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
      <Parameter name="type">gdal</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="file">/path_to_dir/map_slopeshade.tif</Parameter>
    </Datasource>
  </Layer>
</Map>
```

Note: When I transform the TIFFs to EPSG:3857 and replace the Layers `srs` with `srs="+init=epsg:3857"` in the mapfile, the slopeshade is multiplied correctly. But, I don't want to transform my TIFFs for other reasons.

Comment: You don't have a question in your Question.

Comment: @Vince: I do. How to get a multiply layer in the specified projection given the above approach?

Comment: Right now you just have a bunch of statements. You need to [Edit] the Question to add your question.

Comment: The question is onhold because people find it unclear; but I am sure that this is unjustified. There is a link to explain what a multiply layer is, a link to a demonstration how to apply a multiply layer with Mapnik. The example mapfile as shown in the question is not working as expected, as stated. I added a note with the unsatisfying conditions under which I do get the expected results.